# Enable WiX project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, compatibility, wix3.8

I have a VS 2012 solution with WiX Installer projects. However, when I open the solution in VS 2013 (Release) the WiX project is incompatible.

Does anyone know where / whether a VS 2013 version (wixtoolset ?) is available being worked on yet? Or is there a way to make the current project compatible in VS 2013?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Update 2013-12-02:** WiX Toolset 3.8 is released with official support for Visual Studio 2013 editions. It is available for download from [wixtoolset.org](http://wixtoolset.org/).

You can manually enable Visual Studio 2013 compatibility with older versions of WiX:

1. Copy
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WiX` to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WiX`
2. Modify
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WiX\extension.vsixmanifest` by adding the following:

   ```
   <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
       <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
       <Edition>Premium</Edition> 
       <Edition>Pro</Edition>
       <Edition>Express_All</Edition>
   </VisualStudio>
   ```
3. Then open VS2013 Native Tools Command Prompt (from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`) and execute:

   > devenv /setup

When you open Visual Studio 2013, WiX 3.7 projects will be compatible.

Comment: I'm guessing this was taken from my post: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-WiX-3-7-Votive-with-VS2013-RC-td7589257.html

Comment: It should be noted that this won't fully support VS2013.  There is additional work in WiX 3.8 that gets other pieces working such as C++ project templates.

Comment: I had [blogged these instructions](http://www.schiffhauer.com/enable-support-for-wix-3-7-in-visual-studio-2013-rc/) when VS2013 was in Release Candidate on October 14, well before this question. But the instructions are the same as in the nabble link.

Comment: FYI: If you have followed these instructions for 3.7 and install 3.8 you might get this error loading wixproj files:

`The 'WiX Project Package' package did not load correctly.`

I you get it, remove the WiX dir from 

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\` 

and repair the Wix 3.8 setup to get it working again.

Comment: I tried this with 3.6 but didn't get any intellisense whilst typing. :(

Comment: This worked for me on Visual Studio 2015RC using WiX 3.9. Remember to open the Native Tools Command Prompt as an administrator. I found the extension under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WiX

Answer (score 21):

Just update to WiX v3.8, it **does** support VS2013: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3.8/stable

Comment: +1 for the link. As I was using an earlier 3.8 build this is a natural improved solution for me.

Comment: Does anyone know how to use the binaries for off-line installation?  There doesn't appear to be a setup program included.

Answer (score 16):

If you install VS2013 *after* WiX you will have to uninstall WiX then reinstall it. Just repairing the WiX installation is not sufficient.

Comment: OK, didn't for me, but I did not reboot after repairing - also deving on a win2k8 server box - other OSs may be different

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun. It didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

After running the toolkit installer for wix:

For Wix 3.8 and 3.9, with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, I was required to **delete all the cache files** in:

> "%appdata%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache"
>   (for VS 2012) and
>   "%appdata%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache"
>   (for VS 2013) respectively.

**After deleting these files**, execute from command prompt for each version of VS:

```
devenv /setup
```

> e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /setup"
>
> and  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /setup"

Only after I deleted these files and restarted the machine did executing "devenv /setup" have the desired effect.

If these cache files are not deleted first, then you may experience a problem where your packages fail to load properly. You will know if your packages fail to load because VS will fail miserably upon startup.

Comment: I had problems going from WiX 3.8 to 3.9 and getting it working w/VS 2013 the first time. I did this step and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With WiX 3.7, even if you cannot open wixproj in Visual Studio 2013, it does compile using MSBuild for a VS2013 solution. (change wixproj ToolsVersion="12.0")

Answer (score 1):

the latest Wix installer seems to correct the installation without any configuration.

1. close all visual studios. run the .exe at
   https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/136891.
2. A fancy red splashcreen appears, click the centre section titled "install", this
       reinstalls Wix for all versions of VS on your machine.

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade your wix and install WIX 3.9 to make your WIX Project compatible with vs 2013.
Below is the link to download wix 3.9
https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/136891

Comment: After installing wix 3.9 you have to restart your visual studio 2013..then reload wix project..