# Create an application setup in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I already have a project which is ready to build. Currently, I am using visual studio 2013.

But, I don't know how to create an MSI setup in visual studio 2013, but for visual studio 2010 there are plenty of tutorials out there discussing how to create a setup in visual studio 2010.

- Does this mean I need to install visual studio 2010 in order to create an application setup for my project?
- What is the easiest way to create an application setup in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Try [Windows Installer XML (WIX)](https://wix.codeplex.com/) it is extremely customizable and extensible, also you can integrate it with your CI builds. Application setup projects were removed in 2012 you can use the Installshield SE that was included at one point if you still need a quick and dirty installer. [Using WIX in 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455944/332733)

Comment: VS 2012 and after there is no deployment project as in 2010

Comment: how about click once sir @Mgetz? and how do i use the click once?

Comment: @Kaoru I've never gotten Clickonce to work reliably in any version of VS so I won't be much help. But in theory it would work.

Comment: Clickonce has some rather strange peculiarities: You have to execute new versions of the same installation from the original installation directory for it to do an automatic update. Additionally it seems like you have to carry around the attached folder with the clickonce .exe. What I did was wrapping the Clickonce installation stuff inside a SFX archive with winrar, always executing it from the temp directory and essentially creating a "click even less than once installer".

Comment: @Kaoru To use ClickOnce, go into the Publish section of your project's parameters, select where you want it published, and if you application has any assets, do not forget the `application files` button. It will open a window where you can specify whether or not you want to include projects files to the installation.

Answer (score 131):

Microsoft has listened to the cry for supporting installers (MSI) in Visual Studio and release the [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx). You can now create installers in VS2013, [download the extension here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) from the visualstudiogallery.

[visual-studio-installer-projects-extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)

Comment: New and great information.  Microsoft should improve their related article [KB2900817](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2900817)

Comment: @peer Not solution in VS 2012? Alternatives? Full source code samples in VS2012?

Comment: @kiquenet nope, vs2012 is not suported. Most project are upgraded with any work to vs2013 and backwards compatible wit vs2012.

Comment: Don't bother reading the article...it merely tells you to do the following: Go to Tools -> Extensions & Update.  Choose the ONLINE tab.  Search for "Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension"

Comment: I have a VS 2010 solution has a setup project inside, when the solution is built with VS 2010, a msi file is created. Now we only have VS 2013, and I can't change/migrate the setup project. What shall I do to create the msi file?

Comment: You can create a new project with the extension.

Comment: @Peter, can you tell me exactly how? We have no plan to migrate the whole 2010 solution to 2013. If the extension is for 2013, how can I create a new setup project for the 2010 solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

As of Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft no longer provides the built-in deployment package. If you wish to use this package, you will need to use VS2010.

In 2013 you have several options:

- InstallShield
- WiX
- Roll your own

In my projects I create my own installers from scratch, which, since I do not use Windows Installer, have the advantage of being super fast, even on old machines.

Comment: Do you @ming-slogar have any example application with such an installer that you would like to share with us?

Comment: @Highmastdon: I basically just created an installer bootstrapper with native C++ (configured so as to be able to run without pre-installing the C++ runtime libs) which checked for installed .NET and launched a WPF GUI installer. The WPF installer allowed the user to choose a bunch of options and then copied files and wrote registry keys. I don't have a "sample" application - I am using the installer in the project I am working on, but I can try to extract a sample if you need one.

Comment: I'd really want to see a complete example of this. Mind to share? Not the code itself, but the concept and something from your experience? Like how do you *embed* it into project which is going to be installed, how you automate common things (copying list of files, rules: overwrite/not ovewrite, etc). Also, I am using NSIS atm, but I am tired of its scripting language, ugly *modern* UI and very very slow design (it still in the xp stone age).

Comment: @Sinatr To embed assemblies I made heavy use of resource files - both in C++ and C#. To copy files, I was actually lazy and hand-wrote each file operation (e.g. using `File.WriteAllBytes` or `File.WriteAllText`, depending on the file type). I did not handle overwriting existing files - all of my assemblies were prefixed with my app name (e.g. AppName.Controls.dll, AppName.Images.dll) so the chance of a duplicate file would be really small. If you want to handle every single possible scenario you would have to do what Windows Installer does - which sort of defeats the purpose of customizing.

Comment: @Kiquenet I uploaded the code for my custom installer here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4oeYgLcGDfBT29HN2hYLURNT2M&usp=sharing. It will not build due to missing dependencies (I pulled it from a live project), but you can at least see how I created the installer.

Comment: Hi @Ming,  After completing installation of window form MSI setup, my raw files(Design and coding) are also showing at installation location. I've developed this application using visual studio 2010. Setup created successfully, but after installation that MSI this problem is happening. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @dilipkumar1007, please avoid asking unrelated questions in comments -- open a new question instead :).

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2013 now supports setup projects. Microsoft have shipped a Visual Studio extension to produce setup projects.

[Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Hamid, After completing installation of window form MSI setup, my raw files(Design and coding) are also showing at installation location. I've developed this application using visual studio 2010. Setup created successfully, but after installation that MSI this problem is happening. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to understand you question. you have created an installation project with visual studio 2010 & it doesn't work with with visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recommends to use the ["InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio"](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio)  as replacement for the discontinued "Deployment and Setup Project" - but it is not so nice and nobody else recommends to use it. But for simple setups, and if it is not a problem to relay on commercial third party products, you can use it.

The alternative is to use [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](https://wix.codeplex.com/), but you have to do many things manually that did the Setup-Project by itself.

Comment: I completely agree with @Kiquenet - You can try the tutorial from http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

Comment: I install the 2015LE inside the VS 2010, and I can create an IS setup project inside the VS 2010. Now how can I call this project in Jenkins? The InstallShield plugin for Jenkins asks to the path to ISCmdBld.exe, which I can't find in 2015LE.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft also release the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) This is the same extension as the 2013 version but for Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Install Shield and WiX, there is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Although I haven't tried it myself I have heard good things about it.

Answer (score 1):

I will tell , how i solved almost similar problem. I developed a application using VS 2013 and tried to create wizard for it failed to do. Later i installed premium VS and tried and failed.

at last i used "ClickOnce" and it worked fine.

So i believe here also , "CLICKONCE" would help you.