# C# Winform application without source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am developing a Winform application using Visual Studio 2013 and I am trying to get only the executable file without source code.  The executable file in bin wont work if you move it in another location!

EDIT: 
The source file in the BIN as many pointed out work but as long as I do not include SQLite in my application.  Thank you for any helpful comment and answer.

UPDATE: 
I just found a way how to get ONLY the executable file without source code.  I need to get the entire folder Debug/Release.

Comment: What is "trying to get only the executable file without source code"? Do you mean you want to compile your program and only deploy the executable? That's how WinForms development and .NET development works in general.

Comment: Just go to your `bin` folder and grab the executable?

Comment: Do you mean prevent the motivated people from [looking](http://ilspy.net/)?

Comment: @GSerg if that's the case, then also see [.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy) :)

Comment: @CodeCaster most of people are just in rush to answer even without proper read the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your source code folder, go to `bin\Debug`.

If your .exe is not enough, you may want to take a look at this (and consider to update your question): [Create an application setup in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351947/create-an-application-setup-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: What if you're not building in debug?  Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you take only this file to another location, the application wont run.

Comment: @doro Then, you need more than the "executable", I've updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there are not other way?

Comment: @doro As I don't know the resources, libraries, what ever your visual studio project has, I can't answer your question. First thing that went to my mind, is that you are new to the VS2013 and to the .Net environment (and due to that, your app will be simple). If that is not the case, I'll suggest to read about App development in the .Net framework or get a partner who is into that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Does matter whether I am new or not, I am here just for help and not to be judged.

Comment: Me, assuming you are new, is not a judgment, is an assumption. Assumptions are important when you are answering a question. If you think is important to reduce those assumptions, work in adding context when you are asking something. *this is a suggestion, not an order*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58519/discussion-between-celerno-and-doro).