# VS 2013 Cheking for updates

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, publish

I am developing a Windows Forms application with Visual Studio 2013 and i want to publish it in my web site.
I use the VS 2013 publish funcionality using FTP service, it publish it correctly but i see not only a setup.exe is uploaded, but also manifest, and some application carpets...
1.- Is it posible to publish the application under a .msi file?, if so please let me know how.
2.- When i publish it i say to check my page, for example mypage.com, for updates, ¿what should i do in mypage.com when i publish a new version? so when a user is using my app and a new version si avaliable he/she get noticed about it.

sorry for my english and thx in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to publish using Click-Once deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an installer, you can create a msi. 
I used the extension for Vs2013 VSI Bundle. 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

The publish functionality I didn't try with that.
See also the Stackoverflow item: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23339652/200824