# where is the Setup Project in Visual-Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

After a lot of deliberation I finally moved to Visual-studio 2013,

but where is Setup Project in Visual-Studio 2013 ? how to make a package?

Comment: There isn't one. I think it was removed in VS 2012. There's a lot of work that goes into making a good installer and the restrictions of the VS setup project were too many. You can use WiX, Inno Setup or move to a newer model like Click Once or the Windows Store

Comment: `code formatting` is for code, not emphasis.

Comment: They use installshield now.

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351947/create-an-application-setup-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @danish No they don't. It's not included in VS. Installshield is yet-another-installer-builder as far as VS is concerned.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VS2012 onwards does not have anything built in. They recommend getting installshield. I would personally prefer WIX.

Comment: @danish That doesn't mean that Microsoft uses it - in fact you can find blog posts in MSDN about Inno Setup

Comment: So we are **all** wrong and they released a Setup project extension back in June!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Homer voice: DOH!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can use [Visual Studio Installer Project Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx). You can download it from [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx). Also you can find more information in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351947/create-an-application-setup-in-visual-studio-2013).