# How to create set up files for wpf application

Tags: wpf

How can I create set up file for WPF application ? I'm new to WPF applications and I don't have any idea about initializing this.Please help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through below link if you are using VS 2010 and above-

[CREATE SETUP AND DEPLOYMENT OF WPF APPLICATION STEP BY STEP WITH VISUAL STUDIO 2012](http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step-with-visual-studio-2012/)

> You need InstallShield packaging software to after Visual Studio 2008.
>   It will create a template to create deployment project, but you can
>   get the Visual Studio Installer Projects in VS 2010 and above , you
>   need to install the Visual Studio Installer Extension from the Visual
>   Studio Extension Gallery - [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer
>   Projects](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

If you are using VS 2008 then it already have template to create setup project your WPF application. Just follow the below link to know that How use **Setup Project**..

[Create Setup and Deployment of WPF Application Step by Step](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/)

@Hana's answer showing screenshot of the Setup Project, which is used in the VS 2008 to create the deployment package.

References:
[Create an application setup in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351947/create-an-application-setup-in-visual-studio-2013)
[Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects – Hello World Installer](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's a powerfull tools to make setup-wizard for all projects. You can create it easyly. And more features are available with it (icons file, registry management, associate file extension with application, desktop and start menu windows entry, and much more...)

[image: InnoSetup Wizard example]

Answer (score 0):

Using VS 2008:

Add a Setup and Deployment project to the Solution

[image]

As soon as you add the project it opens the File Explorer view.

[image]

add Program File's Folder to our Setup project

[image]

add Primary output and other dependencies to Application Folder.

[image]

Select as displayed above.

[image]

Now we would add A folder to the Program Files Folder.

[image]

Now add the same as you did for the Application Folder.

[image]

add a Shortcut to User's Desktop.

[image]

Rebuild the Solution and then rebuild the Setup project.

Full help is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/)