# How do I get WiX 3.6 to work with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I would like to use WiX 3.6 in my Visual Studio 2013 project.  I use the same computer to compile other projects which the company says must use Wix 3.6 so I don't have the option of upgrading Wix.

I have a Wix project that works under Visual Studio 2008.  I've searched for ways to get Visual Studio 2013 to recognize it, but with no luck.

**EDIT 2014-07-11**

I had looked at the suggested link prior to posting my question, but Visual Studio 2008 does not have the same format of support for extensions that VS2013 has.  So I can't just copy file per the link.

I have VS2010 setup on another machine and copied the extension files from there.  I then followed instructions in the link.  Though, VS2013 now says WIX is an available project type, it fails when I try to create a new WIX project, nor will it recognize my existing WIX project.

[image: Capture of the VS2013 Error Message]

I opened the activity log.  There was a warning and two errors...

(warning)Performance warning: String load failed. Pkg:{E0EE8E7D-F498-459E-9E90-2B3D73124AD5} (WiX Project Package) LANG:0409 ID:100

(error) CreateInstance failed for package [WiX Project Package] {E0EE8E7D-F498-459E-9E90-2B3D73124AD5} 80070002 VisualStudio

(error) End package load [WiX Project Package] {E0EE8E7D-F498-459E-9E90-2B3D73124AD5} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455944/736079

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable WiX project in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448343/enable-wix-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: @jesshouwing - I looked at that answer before posting my question.  That answer does not work for VS2008 because the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions directory does not exist.

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to use 3.6? Version 3.8 has support for VS2013 out of the box.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen - because company requires 3.6 for other projects, did not want to have both installed (not even sure if that's possible)

Comment: Grab the files from a Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 installation instead. Visual Studio 2008 didn't yet support vsix installations.

Comment: I grabbed the files from a Visual Studio 2010 on another machine, then followed instructions in link.  The project fails to load and I cannot create a new Wix project (but VS2013 now show Wix as an available project).  I am going to edit my question.