# Visual Studio 2013 cant load .wixproj with daily builds

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-installer, dailybuilds

I included wix binaries to my TFS and everything works fine for me (I have got Wix installed) but other members of my team cant build an installer because VS2013 prompt an error that .wixproj cannot be loaded and show an migration report. This is expected because they dont have wix installed (read they have a fresh installation of VS2013).

To my understanding this shouldnt happen with the use of wix binaries checked in to TFS.

I followed this documentation post : http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html
and for me it works perfectly.

Help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: The described setup is sufficient for command line building of wix projects (ie msbuild) it is not sufficient for visual studio to open the wix projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448343/enable-wix-project-in-visual-studio-2013